# add multiple JPanels in the middle of the window

Tags: java, swing

I want to create an input `JFrame` where the program reads three fields (model, week and plan), and after inserting one line the user can choose to input new values on a different row, this is done pressing a `JLabel` with a image add icon.
My expectation is to be able to add a new `JPanel` (called body in the subclass) right under the last one (`JPanel lastContent` global variable), and to be able to remove or add new ones as the user needs.
Below is my code so far:

```
package marquesina;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.HorizontalLayout;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.VerticalLayout;

public class JModificaciones extends Container {

private JPanel lastContent;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DEMO");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        JModificaciones mods = new JModificaciones();
        frame.setContentPane(mods);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(
                dim.width / 2 - frame.getSize().width / 2,
                dim.height / 2 - frame.getSize().height / 2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}

public JModificaciones() {
    initComponents();
    System.out.println("New Panel Created");
}

private void initComponents() {
    JPanel jHeader = new JPanel();
    JLabel jLMod = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLSem = new JLabel();
    JLabel jLPlan = new JLabel();
    JPanel jFooter = new JPanel();
    JButton jGuardar = new JButton();
    JButton jCancelar = new JButton();

    setLayout(new VerticalLayout(10));

    //HEADER
    jHeader.setLayout(new HorizontalLayout());

    jLMod.setText("Model");
    jHeader.add(jLMod);

    jLWeek.setText("Week");
    jHeader.add(jLWeek);

    jLPlan.setText("Plan");
    jHeader.add(jLPlan);

    add(jHeader);

    //CONTENT
    add(new jContent());

    //FOOTER
    jGuardar.setText("Save");
    jFooter.add(jGuardar);

    jCancelar.setText("Cancel");
    jFooter.add(jCancel);

    add(jFooter);
}

public class jContent extends JPanel {

    JLabel jAdd = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    JLabel jDelete = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    public jContent() {
        JPanel body = new JPanel(new HorizontalLayout());
        JTextField jModel = new JTextField();
        JTextField jWeek = new JTextField();
        JTextField jPlan = new JTextField();

        body.setLayout(new org.jdesktop.swingx.HorizontalLayout());

        jModel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 28));
        body.add(jModel);

        jWeek.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 28));
        body.add(jWeek);

        jPlan.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 28));
        body.add(jPlan);

        jAdd.setIcon(
                new javax.swing.ImageIcon(
                        getClass().getResource("add.png")));
        jAdd.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

            }
        });
        body.add(jAdd);

        jDelete.setIcon(
                new javax.swing.ImageIcon(
                        getClass().getResource("delete.png")));
        jDelete.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                remove(lastContent);
            }
        });
        body.add(jDelete);

        add(body);
    }
}
```

}

However I'm not able to add a new `JPanel` (which I want to create when the user clicks on the `jAdd JLabel`), I can't come up with a way to reference the `JPanel` where I want to put my new Components and using just add() or remove() as I do in the above code just reference the `MouseListener`, not the `JPanel` created in the sublcass...

Comment: Check this link out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: JLabel is not for user input.  Use a JButton instead.